# Any method to remove some sections in a file or just can be delete lines by lines?(Perl scripts)

Tags: perl

I have a file contains many section but I want remove all sections except section A. 
Example:

```
Section A 
abcdefg

Section B
hijklmn

Section C
opqrstu
```

Any Perl scripts can be write to remove all contents in B and C?

Comment: yes, perl scripts can do this.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code. If you don't have code, then Stack Overflow is not the best place for your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the paragraph mode to read the file by sections, then just use a regex match to verify the section names you want to keep.

```
perl -00 -ne 'print if /^Section A/' -- file
```

Answer (score 0):

@Choroba did give you a one liner for this, so here is a script version

```
use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = "";
open(my $in_fh, "<", "inputfile.txt") or die "unable to open inputfile.txt: $!";
open(my $out_fh, ">", "outputfile.txt") or die "unable to open outputfile.txt: $!";
while ( <$in_fh> ) {
    print $out_fh $_ if /^Section A/;
}

close $in_fh;
close $out_fh;
```

This will open file `inputfile.txt` and read in paragraph mode, find `Section A` and purely print `Section A` as a paragraph into file `outputfile.txt`

giving a result of

```
Section A
abcdefg
```

Answer (score 0):

I always think that programs like this are far more useful if they adhere to the Unix Filter Model - i.e. they read from `STDIN` and write to `STDOUT`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = ''; # paragraph mode

while (<>) {
  print if /^Section A/;
}
```